# Kendo ui dropdown default value

Tags: kendo-ui, dropdown

here's a weird one: In any other parts of my code, this works fine, but in this particular directive, it wont assume the default value being passed. It keeps the select ----- value.

```
function RolesDropDownEditor(container, options) {    
    var _roleID = null;    
    if (options.model.roleID !== null && options.model.roleID !== undefined)
        _roleID = options.model.roleID;    
    $('<input name="Role" id="ddRoles" required="required"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataValueField: "roleID",
        dataSource: $rootScope.globalObjects.dsRoles,
        optionLabel: '--',
        change: function (e)
        {
                options.model.roleID = this.value();
                options.model.dirty = true;
                $scope.$apply();    
        }
    });    
    $("#ddRoles").data("kendoDropDownList").value(_roleID);    
    $("<span class='k-invalid-msg' data-for='Role'></span>").appendTo(container);    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom editor's `name` attribute value (`"Role"`) must match the edited field's name (`"roleID"`), which does not seem to be the case.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom

After this is implemented, you will not have to set `options.model.roleID` manually in the `change` handler of the DropDownList.